# How can I write an After Update Trigger in SQL Server to see the following results

Tags: sql-server, database-trigger

The trigger should update only one record, whenever an update command is sent to the table.

Eg: table `dbo.EmployeeFacts`:

```
UPDATE EmployeeFacts
SET FactNo = 4
WHERE FactNo = 5
```

The necessary columns that are updated when the trigger is fired are :-

1. `edit_status = edit_status + 1`
2. `lastupdate` should be the date when table is updated
3. `UPDBY` is `dbo`
4. rest of the columns will remain as is

[Screenshot of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jtQ4.png)

Comment: You mean to say any update on same table should update only one record ?

Comment: Yeah. Like the update query is fired in the example, it should update only one record as the screenshot.

Comment: @sagi - I have used both insert and update queries. With an update query it is updating all the records, as I am not understanding where to put the WHERE condition.

Comment: You need to look at the inserted virtual table. And DO NOT fall into the fallacy that all updates will only ever affect a single row. This is the most common mistake people make with triggers. They need to handle sets.

Comment: You also can go ahead with instead of update which will be more optimal in your case,since you are basically nullfying any update statement fired and going ahead with a default one of your choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this, you should use factno (as per my assumption it is a primary key column) in where clause filter you should not update the factno column since it is a primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE EmployeeFacts (
    factno INT
    ,empno INT
    ,fact VARCHAR(100)
    ,createdate DATETIME
    ,editstatus INT
    ,lastupdate DATETIME
    ,updby VARCHAR(50)
    )

INSERT INTO EmployeeFacts (
    factno
    ,empno
    ,fact
    ,createdate
    )
VALUES (
    1
    ,1001
    ,'1001A'
    ,getdate()
    )
    ,(
    2
    ,1002
    ,'1002A'
    ,getdate()
    )
    ,(
    3
    ,1003
    ,'1003A'
    ,getdate()
    )
    ,(
    4
    ,1004
    ,'1004A'
    ,getdate()
    )
    ,(
    5
    ,1005
    ,'1005A'
    ,getdate()
    )

SELECT *
FROM EmployeeFacts

CREATE TRIGGER Tr_EmployeeFacts_Upd ON EmployeeFacts
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE e
    SET e.editstatus = isnull(i.editstatus, 0) + 1
        ,e.lastupdate = getdate()
        ,UPDBY = 'dbo'
    FROM EmployeeFacts e
    INNER JOIN inserted i ON e.FactNo = i.FactNo
END
GO

UPDATE EmployeeFacts
SET empno = 1007
WHERE FactNo = 1
```

Comment: It works. Thanks I got it. Was thinking of using the magic tables - inserted and deleted, but didn't know how. Now, I get it how inner join worked for the "where" condition I was talking about.